# How can I change_column_default based on the value selected of another row in a Ruby on Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, column-defaults

Sorry, y'all.  New to Ruby on Rails.
I am updating a profile form that consists of the following YES/NO questions:
[image]

The user table already has an existing `children_under_five` column but I'd like to add a column `has_children` to incorporate whether they have children at all.  The only new field will be `has_children` which, in the event, someone has a child under 5 that means they have a child, so `has_children` should be true for those folks, otherwise it should default to `false`. How can I implement this within the migration itself? This is all I have so far:

```
  def change
    add_column :users, :has_children, :boolean, default: false, null: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an update statement either in that migration or a following one...

```
 def change
   query = <<-SQL
     update users
     set has_children = children_under_five
   SQL

   execute query
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a method here?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def has_children?
    self.children_under_five > 0 ? true : false
  end
end
```

And you can use it as

```
>> user = User.first
   user.has_children? # returns true or false
```

Answer (score -1):

I quite dont understand your question but the question is ? **How to add a column with migration?** well: `rails g migration add_has_children_to_users has_children:boolean` then `rails db:migrate`